# JS duplicating the value of the input

Tags: javascript, input

How can I write the h1 with whatever I write on the input field?

Something like this:

```
<input id="inputtxt" type="text" value="Insert text here..">
<h1 id="newtxt"></h1>
```

```js
<script>
var txtelement

txtelement = document.getElementById("inputtxt").value;
document.getElementById("newtxt").innerHTML=txtelement;

</script>
```

It duplicates when the page loads but not when I write

Comment: make a function of it, and call it on page load and after edit/s to the field

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.oninput` event :

```
document.getElementById("inputtxt").oninput = function(e){
    document.getElementById("newtxt").innerHTML=e.target.value;
};
```

**Note :** You could use placeholder instead of value to show default msg to users inside input field.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
document.getElementById("inputtxt").oninput = function(e){
  document.getElementById("newtxt").innerHTML=e.target.value;
};
```

```html
<input id="inputtxt" type="text" placeholder="Insert text here..">
<h1 id="newtxt"></h1>
```

Comment: Change onkeypress by onkeyup. onkeypress, change only at the second changement not directly after char is enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript function, then call that function when an event happens like onchange, onclick, etc.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<input id="inputtxt" type="text" value="Insert text here.." onkeyup="updateText()" />
<h1 id="newtxt"></h1>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var txtelement
var h1 = document.getElementById("newtxt");
var input = document.getElementById("inputtxt");
function updateText() {
    txtelement = input.value;
    h1.innerHTML=txtelement;
}
```

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/e82jahq2/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add onkeyup event:

```js
var txtelement;
var input = document.getElementById("inputtxt");
var newtxt = document.getElementById("newtxt");
input.onkeyup = function() {
  txtelement = input.value;
  newtxt.innerHTML=txtelement;
};
input.onkeyup()
```

```html
<input id="inputtxt" type="text" value="Insert text here..">
<h1 id="newtxt"></h1>
```